# How can I get my Macos Android emulator to run properly

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the latest macos, and also api 34 sdk of android downloaded and installed. I have a problem where the Google Android emulators dont run. i can see the files on them but they get stuck on launching. How can I fix that?

I tried install haxm, deeleting and recreating emuluators, different types of emuluators expecting them to launch properly.

Comment: Try with a cold boot.

Comment: cold boot worked! Thank you!